# Replacing text of a field with javascript Function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, text

I have a form where I dynamically display checkboxes from an oracle database. But I want to change the checkboxes. This is the text of the form:

```
<form  id = "Options"> 
                     <?php
                    $conn = oci_connect('DBadmin', 'dbadmin', 'PETLOVERSDB');
                    if (!$conn) {
                        $e = oci_error();
                        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
                    } 
                                $query= 'select * from pettype order by PET_TYPE_CODE';
                                $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);
                                oci_execute($stmt); 


                                    while($row=oci_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {                
                                         echo "<label>{$row['PET_TYPE_NAME']}</label><input  type = 'checkbox'  name = 'radio' id = '{$row['PET_TYPE_CODE']}'  value = '{$row['PET_TYPE_NAME']}'/><br /> "  ;        
                                    }                

                     ?>   
                    </form>
```

And I also created a function that I call when I press a button:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function update(){  
            var e = document.getElementById("consultFacts");
            var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            alert(str);  
            var elem = document.getElementById("Options");
            elem.value = "My default value";

    }
  </script>
```

I have tried the getElementById as I've read but I don't seem to get any changes in the form. And it does enter the function because it does alert(str). Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want to change? In your update() function, you are just changing the value of the form, which... does nothing. The form contains the inputs. If you want to change the value of an input, you have to find that input, and not the form.

Comment: I want to change everything that is on the form and replace it with other checkboxes. How could I change that?

Comment: You can change its innerHTML. That'll change all of the elements inside of it. `someForm.innerHTML = someMarkup`. You can also 'empty' it's content with innerHTML, and append elements to it with appendChild.

Comment: Yeah, document.getElementById('Options').innerHTML = 'Fred Flinstone';  works just fine but how could I add php (dynamically created checkboxes like the one above) instead of a text cause if i tried adding it after .innerHTML and nothing happened ? Is it possible ? If not what could I do ?

Comment: Well, PHP is server-side code, and your update function is client-side JavaScript. So you can either generate your checkboxes client-side with a loop (similar to your PHP loop for generating the boxes, but in JS) and then append that HTML to your form with either innerHTML or appendChild (depends on how you generate the HTML) OR, you can send an AJAX request to some server-side script that either spits back the full HTML needed for the checkboxes, or JSON data that will help you generate those boxes in the client side of things, so that you can append the new content to your form.